# Unable to start XMonad in Mac

Tags: macos, xmonad

I have completed every step in [XMonad's tutorial](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Using_xmonad_on_Apple_OSX) for Mac.
However, I cannot start it.

My shell did not run my .profile initially properly. My PATH works now correctly.
I run the following command unsuccessfully

```
startx
```

and I get

```
font_cache: Scanning user font directories to generate X11 font caches
font_cache: Updating FC cache
xauth:  creating new authority file /Users/Masi/.serverauth.2188

Xquartz: X11.app = /Applications/Utilities/X11.app/Contents/MacOS/X11
Xquartz: Starting X server: /Applications/Utilities/X11.app/Contents/MacOS/X11 --listenonly
X11.app: main(): argc=2
        argv[0] = /Applications/Utilities/X11.app/Contents/MacOS/X11.bin
        argv[1] = --listenonly
Waiting for startup parameters via Mach IPC.
X11.app: do_start_x11_server(): argc=6
        argv[0] = /usr/X11/bin/X
        argv[1] = :0
        argv[2] = -nolisten
        argv[3] = tcp
        argv[4] = -auth
        argv[5] = /Users/Masi/.serverauth.2188
Xquartz starting:
X.Org X Server 1.4.2-apple42
Build Date: 20090517
(EE) XKB: Couldn't open rules file /usr/X11/share/X11/xkb/rules/base
(EE) XKB: Couldn't open rules file /usr/X11/share/X11/xkb/rules/base
font_cache: Done
```

I have tried to use XMonad unsuccessfully by pressing

```
Ctrl-Shift Enter
```

I get nothing with the command.

**How can you start XMonad successfully in Mac Leopard?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

/usr/X11/lib/X11/xinit/xinitrc is a text file you can't execute it, you should run X11 with

`open -a X11`

Comment: You should write exec /path/to/xmonad in your ~/.xinitrc file.

Comment: I copied my xinitrc -file to my home. I found the file from the command locate xinitrc at my root. I replaced twm by xmonad. I still get the above error in my message.

Comment: Perhaps, my Mac does not read my .xinitrc at my home. How can I test the fact?

Comment: @cartman: I put your command in your comment to my xinitrc unsuccessfully. I can see no difference when I start my terminal again.

Comment: It should be .xinitrc notice the dot before the filename.

Comment: Please, see my revised question. The 1st problem was in my PATH.